# IEnumerable Method with AsParallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, thread-safety

I got the following extension method:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequencise<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> input,
        int subsequenceLength)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
        SubsequenciseParameter parameter = new SubsequenciseParameter
            { 
                Next = enumerator.MoveNext()
            };

        while (parameter.Next)
                yield return getSubSequence(
                    enumerator,
                    subsequenceLength,
                    parameter);         
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> getSubSequence<T>(
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator,
        int subsequenceLength,
        SubsequenciseParameter parameter)
    {
        do
        {
            lock (enumerator) // this lock makes it "work"
            {                 // removing this causes exceptions.
                if (parameter.Next)
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
            }

        } while ((parameter.Next = enumerator.MoveNext())
                  && --subsequenceLength > 0);
    }

    // Needed since you cant use out or ref in yield-return methods...
    class SubsequenciseParameter
    {
        public bool Next { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Its purpose is to split a sequence into subsequences of a given size.

Calling it like this:

```
foreach (var sub in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                    .Subsequencise(3)
                    .**AsParallel**()
                    .Select(sub =>new String(sub.ToArray()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(sub);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

works, however there are some empty lines in-between since some of the threads are "too late" and enter the first yield return.

I tried putting more locks everywhere, however I cannot achieve to make this work correct in combination with as parallel.

It's obvious that this example doesn't justify the use of as parallel at all. It is just to demonstrate how the method could be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that using iterators is lazy evaluated, so you return a lazily evaluated iterator which gets used from multiple threads.

You can fix this by rewriting your method as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequencise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int subsequenceLength)
{
    var syncObj = new object();
    var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield break;
    }

    List<T> currentList = new List<T> { enumerator.Current };
    int length = 1;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (length == subsequenceLength)
        {
            length = 0;
            yield return currentList;
            currentList = new List<T>();                
        }
        currentList.Add(enumerator.Current);
        ++length;
    }
    yield return currentList;
}
```

This performs the same function, but doesn't use an iterator to implement the "nested" `IEnumerable<T>`, avoiding the problem.  Note that this also avoids the locking as well as the custom `SubsequenciseParameter` type.

Comment: Good answer, however it's worth to mention that it comes with a price - accumulation.

Comment: @BartoszKP Accumulation?  The only accumulated values are the "nested" sequences, which are going to be quite small.  The overall process is still streamed...  There should be very little "price" associated here (unless, of course, you're dealing with *very large* sequence sizes)

Comment: Whether it's a big price or small depends on the usage context. From my experience when you need batching, then usually sequences are *very large* and OP's solution didn't need any accumulation (true that it didn't work though :) ). Don't mean to argue that it is a big drawback - as I said, I find the answer very nice :)

Comment: @BartoszKP The accumulation only happens within the individual batches, not the entire sequence.  For example, if you have 100000000 elemetns, and take in sequences of 5, I'm only ever storing 1 `List<T>` with 5 elements.  That's why there's low overhead.  The million is still streamed through the process.

Comment: Yes, I understand your code and I didn't say that the overhead isn't low.  I was rather considering 10 batches with 100000 element lists, or 1000x1000. And again - I'm not saying that it's a big issue...

Comment: @BartoszKP Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way around this, unless you know more about the input collection (ie: if the input collection was an `IList<T>`...)

Comment: I designed the method around the idea to make it not accumulate at all. Depending on subsequence-size this is actually a drawback for me. However if this means this is the way to make it "Parallel" this would be an acceptable drawback. Thank you.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, I'm criticizing but unfortunately doesn't have any better idea ;)